# How to fix HTTP error in Python 3 using urlopen with urllib

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, urllib

I have added a user agent in the header. The following is my code and the error

```
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1)'}

domain=Request("http://online-courses.club/baugasm-series-8-design-abstract-textures-and-poster-with-acrylic-paint-photoshop-and-cinema-4d/",data=bytes(json.dumps(headers), encoding="utf-8"))
response =urlopen(domain)
```

I also tried a different version, note the change in domain variable

```
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1)'}

domain=Request("http://online-courses.club/baugasm-series-8-design-abstract-textures-and-poster-with-acrylic-paint-photoshop-and-cinema-4d/",headers)
response =urlopen(domain)
```

None of these codes are working.
The error:

```
line 9, in <module>
    response =urlopen(domain)
  File "C:\Users\ABC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\urllib\request.py", line 222, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Users\ABC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\urllib\request.py", line 531, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "C:\Users\ABC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\urllib\request.py", line 641, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "C:\Users\ABC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\urllib\request.py", line 569, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "C:\Users\ABC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\urllib\request.py", line 503, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\ABC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\urllib\request.py", line 649, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.add_header()` to add correct `User-Agent`.

For example:

```
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen

domain=Request("http://online-courses.club/baugasm-series-8-design-abstract-textures-and-poster-with-acrylic-paint-photoshop-and-cinema-4d/")
domain.add_header('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0')
response =urlopen(domain)

print(response.read())
```

Prints:

```
b'<!DOCTYPE html>\r\n<html lang="en-US" prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#">\r\n<head itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="http://schema.org/WebSite">\r\n\t<meta charset="UTF-8" />

... and so on.
```